# Having trouble on Wix upgrade installer - Error 1409 - Could not read security information for key

Tags: wix, installation, registry

6-23: I have gotten everything else completed on this installation except for this one bug. It is still sticking around. I would love to hear some more opinions on the cause. I have the full verbose log of the event as well as the wxs file where the keys are being entered.

UPDATE 6-11-15: I found out much more relevant information on this bug.

This log snippet shows that the windows installer is unable to find a registry key: http://pastebin.com/JBH3DukW

I checked my registry and that key was already gone! Then when the install backs out and fails, it puts it right back. I have a strong belief that the key is being removed twice, with the second deletion causing the installer to fail. I have narrowed my xml post down the the relevant component. Does this sound like a double delete to you? Is it something in my code?

Error spit out by the installer GUI:

"Could not read security information for key SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\lr-grafana\Parameters. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personal."

This error only pops up SOMETIMES. I would guess about 10% of the time. This error shows up regardless of if the service is running or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Component Id="nssm.exe" Guid="{7ACB6DB9-0E50-452D-B403-689B39957A8C}">
        <!-- nssm actually runs the service, so we have to set it as the key -->
        <File Id="nssm.exe" Name="nssm.exe" Source="$(var.SOURCEDIR)..\Common\bin\nssm.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
        <ServiceInstall
          Id="ServiceInstaller"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Vital="yes"
          Name="$(var.SERVICENAME)"
          DisplayName='$(var.ProductName)'
          Description='$(var.ServiceDescription)'
          Start="auto"
          Account="LocalSystem"
          ErrorControl="ignore"
          Interactive="no"
              >
          <util:ServiceConfig xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
                FirstFailureActionType="restart"
                SecondFailureActionType="restart"
                ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
                ResetPeriodInDays="1"
                RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="60"
                />  <!-- note: Windows Service Properties only displays the RestartDelay in min -->
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="$(var.SERVICENAME)" Wait="yes" />
        <!-- the sub reg keys needed by nssm -->
        <RegistryKey
          Root="HKLM"
          Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\$(var.SERVICENAME)\Parameters"
          >

          <RegistryValue Type="expandable" Name="Application" Value="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" />
          <RegistryValue Type="expandable" Name="AppParameters" 
            Value='-Dlogback.configurationFile=$(var.ProductKey)-logback-persistent.xml -Dservice.name=$(var.ProductKey) -classpath sqljdbc4.jar;$(var.ProductKey).jar com.Company.carpenter.Carpenter' />
          <RegistryValue Type="expandable" Name="AppDirectory" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
          <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="AppStopMethodSkip" Value="6" />
          <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="AppStopMethodConsole" Value="10000" />

          <RegistryValue Key="AppExit" Type="string" Value="Exit" />
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
```

Comment: It might narrow it down if you do a verbose log. It looks like the Service install or delete, or the util config, or the registrykey could be associated with that error. Then there would be something to focus on.

Comment: Could your company adopt (or allow) a version scheme that is more Windows Installer friendly? One that uses the first three numbers to uniquely identify each build.

Comment: @PhilDW I didn't know I could get a log of the installer while it works (new to wix). I will try that!

Comment: @bradfordrg We spoke of this, and they seemed open to the idea, but getting this working with the current build scheme is ideal

Comment: I checked the logs, here is a post of the events leading up to the failure: 

http://pastebin.com/SLc7RS82

Comment: I think it's got to be that the service (or at least the process itself) is still running/shutting down. It may no longer be running as a service but the process may be slow going away. That's the most likely explanation for it being (apparently) a timing issue.

Comment: @PhilDW - That sounds like a very good guess. Any advice as to how I slow down the transition from killing the service to removing it's registry entries?

Comment: I just suspect that the service is still being shutdown and has those registry entries are in use, something like that, but it depends on the service and what it does during shutdown. Wait=yes just means wait until it's not a service, but the process can still be there, and of course it's just code - it can lie/have a bug and say it's not a service when it still is. Note that the log shows more than 10 seconds to stop the service, so it doesn't appear to be very responsive.

Comment: Hmm, well the only thing I can say to that is this error happens randomly across my 10 msi's. I have a burn install that ties them all together and, roughly every 3 uninstalls, one of them throws this error and the whole install backs out.  I'm really hopeful that this is an install configuration error on my end.

Comment: UPDATE: That same error showed up during an uninstall when none of the services were running. So this is confirmed to not be a timing issue with the services shutting down on uninstall.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I revamped the question. I found out much more narrowed-down information regarding the error.

Comment: Still needing help on this question. This is a very hurtful bug to my team's automation since we are outsourcing it and the receiving team is a bit stiff when it comes to hiccups in the testing.